# Nothing opens after GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-7, grubrescue

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 as a dual boot. I generally use Ubuntu and very rarely use Windows. I recently tried to open Windows 7 and it entered the Startup Repair screen. It took too long to complete, so I restarted the PC.

After restarting I chose Ubuntu from the GRUB menu. It started, but ran too slowly and finally hung. I again restarted and thereafter it either freezes into a gray screen after choosing any entry from the GRUB menu or even before showing the GRUB menu into a black screen. Nothing shows up and the screen remains constant. I looked through many questions on Ask Ubuntu, but none of them helped. Also if the screen freezes after choosing Ubuntu from GRUB screen, then on pressing **Ctrl**+**Alt**+**Del** the computer reboots. No other key sequences work - everything remains constant.

Everything was fine previously and I've not added any recent hardware so a driver problem doesn't seem to be a issue.

My system specs are as follows:

⠀Intel Core 2 Duo E7300
⠀2GB RAM
⠀Seagate 250GB hard disk
⠀Intel chipset G33 graphics

Please do not mark this as a duplicate as none of the other solutions in the suggested questions seemed to work.

Comment: I guess Windows (and restarting it midway) has screwed up your bootloader or partition table. You can use a live usb disk to run gparted and see if partition table is as it used to be (and do a disk check). Also you can update the Grub as explained here: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i updated the question with the specs for my PC. By freezes I mean that nothing shows up on the screen. The screen color remains as is. As I wrote I the question that everything was fine before and I didn't add any new hardware recently so there's no driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSD's in your computer...

A shot in the dark suggestion is to check your hard drives and peripherals. I'm guessing that you hard powered off your computer during Windows repair so it may have caused a power problem. If you have any other storage devices like a SSD used for caching, it could have been temporarily damaged so that may be causing Ubuntu to hang indefinitely if its not working correctly.

Comment: I don't have any SSDs just single seagate 250 GB hard disk.